# Is there a way to send one data package from multiple input fields as 1 package to Firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, proyecto26.restclient

I'm sending info from 3 input fields on a mobile app made in Unity (Coded in C#) to Firebase database, but as you can see it seems to send each input field's data individually then stacks it on top of one another.[See attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unmDv.png) Ideally I'd only want the last set of complete information.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Proyecto26;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerScores : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField dateText;
    public InputField classText;
    public InputField informationText;

    User user = new User();

    public static string Information;
    public static string Class;
    public static string Date;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {

    }

    public void OnSubmit()
    {
        Date = dateText.text;
        PostToDatabase();

        {
            Class = classText.text;
            PostToDatabase();
        }

        {
            Information = informationText.text;
            PostToDatabase();
        }
    }

    public void OnGetScore()
    {
        RetrieveFromDatabase();

    }

    private void PostToDatabase()
    {
        User user = new User();
        RestClient.Put("https://anti-bullying-demo.firebaseio.com/" + Date + Class + Information + ".json", user);
    }

    private void RetrieveFromDatabase()
    {
        RestClient.Get<User>("https://anti-bullying-demo.firebaseio.com/" + Date + Class + Information + ".json").Then(response =>
        {
            user = response;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OnSubmit()` function call, you call `PostToDatabase()` three times - you only need call it once at the end.

```
public void OnSubmit()
{
    Date = dateText.text;

    {
        Class = classText.text;
    }

    {
        Information = informationText.text;
    }

    PostToDatabase();
}
```